# List of mailings with public view

Tags: civimail

I can't seem to find any info on this so don't know if it exists!  I would like to create a page that provides a list of all recent mailings from civiMail but with just their public view behind the link.  Is there something like that?
Running CiviCRM 4.7.29 and Wordpress 4.9.5.

Thanks
Norm

Comment: not aware that civi gives this sort of listing out of the box

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I solved this problem by using the Wordpress plugin called Postie.  I added the email account associated with the plugin to the group I send the emails too, and voila, it now lists them out in their full html glory.

This was pretty easy to set up and most people should be able to do it.

Norm

Comment: There are similar email-to-post plug-ins/extensions for other CMSs. I like the simplicity of this solution, but I'd still like to see a Public Mail Archive as part of CiviMail core. It seems like a pretty basic feature that every other mass mail service has.

Answer (score 7):

List of mailings are not directly available for anonymous or authentic user with limited permission. However you can have it available in one of the 2 ways

1. Using [Public Mailing Archive](https://civicrm.org/extensions/public-mailings-archive) extension(You will need to tweak code to work as per your requirements for example this extension list Mailings using Mailing subject, change the variable in tpl file to use Mailing name)
2. Create copy of Mailing Summary report and give access to Anonymous user. (I would create an extension that will add a special permission and use hook to alter the link of Mailing Name to use mailing view link).

HTH

Pradeep